# Port not open when using portable wifi hotspot

Tags: wifi-hotspot

I just bought a Samsung S4 and am using its portable wifi hotspot feature for internet connectivity on my laptop when I go out the house.
Works just fine when browsing the web(actually quite fast) but when I use uTorrent, it has an orange exclamation point icon near the bottom right. Downloads are slow even if I have 20-30+ seeders(around 6-10kbps max). Did a quick google search and found out(using canyouseeme.org and port forwarder port checker tool) that the port used by uTorrent is not open.

Checked my windows firewall exception and there's already an exception for uTorrent. I've even added new inbound and outbound rule to specify the port used by uTorrent but no luck.

I believe I've covered everything on my laptop (win 7 64bit). 
BTW, when using the same laptop but using my parent's dsl connection, DL speeds jump to a couple of mbps of the same torrent(facepalm).

Sorry if post is long. I just wanted to explain it thoroughly and to show the things I did to try and resolve the problem. I'm just new to android. Be gentle (but not too much.... harhar!)

Is there anything I need to do on my S4? Hopefully without rooting it. Or to my laptop? 
Thanks a bunch guys. :D

Comment: Most likely the port doesn't get forwarded from your S4 to your laptop. You might want to take a look at [Port Forwarder](http://www.appbrain.com/app/at.bherbst.net) or [other port-forwarding apps](http://www.appbrain.com/search?q=port%20forward). Please report back if that does the trick.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Izzy. I'll download some of those apps and experiment a bit. I've already got the Port Forwarder but the settings are not that easy to tweak with. On a side note, I've always thought the my S4 would act as a modem and not as router wherein I'd have to forward ports to it.

Comment: I am having the same issue and I am new with android too... did you succeed ? I don't understand the port forwarding maybe... (sorry about my english ...)